# How to change TabBarController index and call method

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UIButton in one of my tabBar view's controller and I want that button to change the tabBar selectedIndex and call that selectedIndex's controller method.

Example:
My button is selectedIndex 3. When the user clicks the button, I want to change the selectedIndex to 0 and call a method in that selectedIndex's controller.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you have a `UIButton` in one of the views, which when tapped would select a different `UITabBarItem` (thus changing views as if the user tapped on the tab bar item itself)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can switch to a different tab:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

    /* Running method declared in FirstViewController */

    FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

    // call methods here
    [firstView methodName];    

    [firstView release];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya you can do it easily....just use this in your button event method

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
```